# Query utilizando dos filas de una misma tabla en Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

agradecere me puedan orientar con el siguiente resultado que deseo obtener.

Necesito unir en una sola fila ...dos filas, como se aprecia en la imagen debo convertir la fila "color rojo y color factor rojo" en una nueva que se llame "mezcla rojo" está union debe basarse en la columna "color" debe unir todas las filas que contengan el color en su descripción en este ejemplo "la palabra rojo", y a su vez sumar sus columnas enero, febrero y marzo :

Tabla original :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Query que deseo obtener :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo la query con la tabla temporal, desconozco como hacer esto y si es posible...gracias a todos!!!

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE total_color (
 color VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
, enero INT NOT NULL
, febrero INT NOT NULL
, marzo INT NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO total_color (color, enero, febrero, marzo) VALUES ('azul', 1200, 1350, 1000);
INSERT INTO total_color (color, enero, febrero, marzo) VALUES ('amarillo', 1000, 900, 1200);
INSERT INTO total_color (color, enero, febrero, marzo) VALUES ('rojo', 400, 300, 410);
INSERT INTO total_color (color, enero, febrero, marzo) VALUES ('factor rojo', 50, 25, 50);


SELECT * FROM total_color;
```

Comment: Explica cuál es el criterio que se debe seguir para unir esas filas. Por ejemplo, que contengan la palabra `rojo` en la columna `color`  ... Es un detalle fundamental que no aportas en el planteamiento de la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, lo acabo de editar espero se entienda. La union debe basarse en la columna color, deben unirse todas las filas que en su columna color hagan mención a uno de los colores existentes, en este caso debe unir todas las filas que contengan la palabra rojo en la columna color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción sería crear una tabla de colores (con los nombres de los colores), luego hacer un `INNER JOIN` entre tu tabla y las de colores (utilizando `like`), agrupando por el nombre del color (de la tabla colores) y sumando las demás columnas.

```
CREATE TABLE colores (
      nombre varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO colores VALUES ('azul'), ('amarillo'), ('rojo');
```

Query:

```
SELECT c.nombre AS color, 
       sum(enero) AS enero, 
       sum(febrero) AS febrero, 
       sum(marzo) AS marzo
FROM total_color tc
INNER JOIN colores c ON tc.color like concat('%', c.nombre, '%')
GROUP BY c.nombre;
```

Puedes concatenar la palabra "mezcla" al nombre del color cuando al agrupar hay mas de 1 fila, utiliznado `CASE` y `count(*)`:

```
CASE WHEN count(*) = 1 THEN c.nombre ELSE concat('mezcla ', c.nombre) END AS color,
```

| color | enero | febrero | marzo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| azul | 1200 | 1350 | 1000 |
| amarillo | 1000 | 900 | 1200 |
| mezcla rojo | 450 | 325 | 460 |

**Importante:**

Tienes que tener en cuenta que si una fila tiene el nombre de dos colores de la tabla colores, entonces la va a vincular dos veces. Ej: si en tu tabla hubiera un color "amarillo azulado" lo vincularía con los colores amarillo y azul y lo sumaría una vez en cada color; pero puedes buscar estrategías para resolverlo según los casos que se presenten.

Comment: Gracias nachospiu me brindaste la idea que necesitaba, ya tenía la tabla exterior para manejar los colores pero no la estaba realacionando y eso es un error, ademas desconocia el uso de la sentencia like en un join...muchas gracias!!!

Comment: De nada @FernandoAguayo!!! Me alegra haberte ayudado.